# Using Spring.Net to inject dependencies into ASP.NET MVC ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, spring.net, mvccontrib, action-filter

I'm using MvcContrib to do my Spring.Net ASP.Net MVC controller dependency injection.
My dependencies are not being injected into my CustomAttribute action filter.
How to I get my dependencies into it?

Say you have an ActionFilter that looks like so:

```
public class CustomAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, ICustomAttribute
{
    private IAwesomeService awesomeService;

    public CustomAttribute(){}

    public CustomAttribute(IAwesomeService awesomeService)
    {
          this.awesomeService= awesomeService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
         //Do some work
    }
}
```

With a Spring.Net configuration section that looks like so:

```
<object id="CustomAttribute " type="Assembly.CustomAttribute , Assembly" singleton="false">
    <constructor-arg ref="AwesomeService"/>
</object>
```

And you use the Attribute like so:

```
[Custom]
public FooController : Controller
{
    //Do some work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tough part here is that ActionFilters seem to get instantiated new with each request and in a context that is outside of where Spring is aware.  I handled the same situations using the Spring "ContextRegistry" class in my ActionFilter constructor.  Unfortunately it introduces Spring specific API usage into your code, which is a good practice to avoid, if possible.

Here's what my constructor looks like:

```
public MyAttribute()
{
    CustomHelper = ContextRegistry.GetContext().GetObject("CustomHelper") as IConfigHelper;
}
```

Keep in mind that if you are loading multiple Spring contexts, you will need to specify which context you want in the GetContext(...) method.

Comment: That's the only way I have been able to do it since most inject scenarios start with the controller.  You could set the default DependencyResolver in MVC to use a Spring based on that you need to implement....this will keep the Spring specific code outside of your attributes.