# How to do Spring.NET DI injection in action filters (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, spring.net, action-filter

Tried to search but no specific answers (I am very new in this)...

With Spring.NET supporting ASP.NET MVC 3, how can I do dependency injection inside action filters? Studied around but I have no clue at all! :/

On Spring.NET documentary, it appears to mention that this has all been taken care of, all that's needed to do is to just register the action filter into spring's context and spring will take care of all the necessary injection process.

http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web-mvc3.html

However, I just can't get it to work. Studying around blogs and etc, there are mentions of using filter providers, or directly using ContextRegistry.GetContext(), but this doesn't appear to adhere to AOP..

[Using Spring.Net to inject dependencies into ASP.NET MVC ActionFilters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830376/using-spring-net-to-inject-dependencies-into-asp-net-mvc-actionfilters)

[Spring.Net & Attribute Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562219/spring-net-attribute-injection)

So what's the proper way to do this? I thought this is already covered by spring.net, but it appears that it isn't.

I referenced to Spring.Web.Mvc3 v4.0.30319, and I am running on ASP.NET MVC 3.

**EDIT:**

I tried this:

```cs
SpringMvcDependencyResolver dr = 
       new SpringMvcDependencyResolver(ContextRegistry.GetContext());
```

and then getting the service via `dr.GetService<ITestService>();` This seems to make it work somewhat, but instead of getting the correct actual service implementation (on my Filters.xml, I wrote the property ref to `TestService`), it returns the Stub version of the service. Did I do it wrong? Or do I have to sift through and pick the right one or something via `GetServices()`?

**EDIT2:**

@Andreas: Sorry for the late reply. But, my `Global.asax` DOES have it in.

`public class MvcApplication : Spring.Web.Mvc.SpringMvcApplication`

To test, I have this in my spring config:

```
<object type="Spring.Mvc3QuickStart.Filters.TestFilter, Spring.Mvc3QuickStart" singleton="false" >
  <property name="Message" value="This is the ActionFilter message" />
</object>
```

In my filter:

```
public class TestFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.ActionMessage = Message;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

In my controller I have this:

`ViewData["Message"] = Message;`

So purely for this test project, the Filter should have the message injected. But the output isn't as expected.

Comment: Could you please post the relevant parts of your spring config? Prop injection to action filter works ootb when you derive your global.asax from SpringMvcApplication.

Comment: @Andreas: Edited to answer your questions :)

Hmm.. not exactly sure my edits match the text properly, seems like they aren't showing well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.3.2 release of Spring.Net.Mvc3 seams to be a bit buggy. In `SpringMvcDependencyResolver` the method `public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)` will always fail. It should be `return services.Values.Cast<object>();` instead of `return services.Cast<object>();`. The simplest fix is to override `BuildDependencyResolver` of `SpringMvcApplication` and register your own fixed `SpringMvcDependencyResolver`.

I created a complete solution hosted here:
https://gist.github.com/1262927

Comment: Have you reported this bug and fix? Would be appdeciated, i think. Spring.net is now hosted at github.

Comment: @Marijn: The case is [SPRNET-1473](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1473).

Comment: @Andreas, would this mean in the end that I still need to use GetServices and sift through the IEnumerable? Hmm I'm confusing myself lol.

May I ask, could you kindly provide a working sample of this? Not really able to get IApplicationContext and ContextRegistry to work through an override.. I might be missing some form of reference.

Comment: You will find a complete sample here: http://andreaskluth.net/SpringSample/SpringActionFilterSample.zip